# Chain of subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Given a chain of subgroups $K<H<G$

a.) Prove or disprove: if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

b.) Prove or disprove: if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $K$ is a normal subgroup of $H$.

I know a subgroup is normal if $gH=Hg$ for all $g$ in $G$ but I'm not sure how to expand that to the rest of the groups or if it's even possible.

Tom

Comment: I never liked Prove/Disprove questions, because it's too easy to waste time deciding whether something's true or not. So my contribution will be to say that a) is false, and b) is true.

Comment: You and me both my friend. I don't have the mind for proofs.

Comment: To prove that b) is true is straight forward: If $gK=Kg$ for all $g\in G$, then in particular $gK=Kg$ for all $g\in H$ (since $H\subset G$).

Answer (score 1):

a) False, let $K =\langle(12)(34)\rangle, H=\{(12)(34),(13)(42),(23)(41),e\}$, and $G=S_4$

b) True, $gK=Kg$ for all $g \in G$, $g \in H$ implies $g \in G$ so $gK=Kg$ for all $g\in H$ and so $K$ is normal in $H$.